Excel AVERAGEIFS and CHOOSECOLS
I'm trying to calculate the following AVERAGEIFS with CHOOSECOLS inside.

A1# is a spilled formula that comes from somewhere else. You can see that A1# looks like a table.
G1# contains =UNIQUE( CHOOSECOLS(A1#,1) ) and works as expected.
I want to have the average of the second column  (or any other in general) of A1# for each unique element in the first column of A1# as a spilled formula. This works fine when I do it the rookie way like =AVERAGEIFS(B1:B10,A1:A10,G1#), but somehow using CHOOSECOLS breaks it.

Any ideas?

PS: Sorry for Spanish. In the picture PROMEDIO.SI.CONJUNTO = AVERAGEIFS, ELEGIRCOLS = CHOOSECOLS and in Spanish we use ; instead of ,

Use INDEX() not CHOOSECOLS() --> =AVERAGEIFS(INDEX(A1:C10,,3),INDEX(A1:C10,,1),E1#)

UNIQUE() works both with array object as well as range object but those belong to IFs family don't work with array object, CHOOSECOLS() returns an array while INDEX() function returns a reference range. This goes same with COUNTIF()+s , SUMIF()+s and MAXIF()+s

Good to know @MayukhBhattacharya Is this behavior documented by Microsoft? Any links?

Refer the first line under release notes CHOOSECOLS() and see for INDEX()

Try using INDEX() instead of CHOOSECOLS()


=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX(A1#,,2),INDEX(A1#,,1),E1#)


Or, one formula:
=LET(
     α, UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(A1#,1)),
     HSTACK(α, AVERAGEIFS(INDEX(A1#,,2),INDEX(A1#,,1),α)))


Another alternative, using GROUPBY():
=GROUPBY(CHOOSECOLS(A1#,1),CHOOSECOLS(A1#,2),AVERAGE,,0)


NOTE: UNIQUE() works both with array object as well as range object but those belong to IFs family don't work with array object, CHOOSECOLS() returns an array while INDEX() function returns a reference range. This goes same with COUNTIF()+s , SUMIF()+s and MAXIF()+s. 
